# error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *’ from type ‘digestInfo’

Tags: c

This will become apparent that I am a newly at C programming. (I know other languages, especially PHP well, but wanted to have a go at C).

I've managed to hack some code together which is working exactly the way I want it - and I'm now extending it a little more - and I can't figure out how to do it.

Some background. I'm working with this object:

```
typedef struct
{
   dsUint16_t   stVersion;                       
... (omitted for clarity)
   dsUint16_t   objInfoLength;                  
   char         *objInfo;                       
... (omitted for clarity)
}ObjAttr;
```

To me, the *ObjInfo is an area that I can use to store some data, which will be an object (struct?), so I have created by typedef:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int stVersion ;                /* structure version */
    const EVP_MD *digest_id ;               /* digest name */
    unsigned char digest_value ;            /* digest calculated value (Variable length) */
//  ...                                     /* in the future I may want to store something else */
} digestInfo ;
```

I have this struct in a .h file, so that it can be referenced in 2 of my .c files.

Now in .c file, where I am storing this data (which ends up in a application database), I have this code:

```
...
ObjAttr objAttr;
digestInfo digestO;
...
memset(&digestO,0x00,sizeof(digestO));
digestO.stVersion = 1;
digestO.digest_id = EVP_get_digestbyname(digest);
...
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
digestO.digest_value = *md_value;

objAttr.objInfo = *digestO;
objAttr.objInfoLength = sizeof(digestO);
```

When I compile, I get this error:

```
error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘digestInfo’)
```

I know its because I am trying to store the digestInfo object into a char value - how should I do that?

I have tried combinations of

```
objAttr.objInfo = digestO;
objAttr.objInfo = &digestO;
```

But still get an error of sorts (although the last one does compile with an warning).

Am I on the right track here? (Basically I'm calculating the MD5 of some data coming in via STDIN (which is being stored in the application), and I want to store my hash calcs in the "objInfo" area of ObjAttr.

I want to include the algorithm used (md5, sha1, etc), with the resulting hash, so that when I retrieve that data, I can re-run the digest to make sure that I still get the same hash.

If I'm way of track with this, would somebody mind pointing me back in the right direction?

Am I right to use memset first, to zero out the memory?

Should I be worried that each of these vars (digest_id,digest_value) could have a variable length?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as C++, maybe you should re-tag.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  "`.c`" files using `memset` and `typedef struct {` identify C code, not C++.  I am taking the liberty to edit this question to get you a better C audience, although you are welcome to leave a comment here if you think that I did that incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks Drew, appreciate the help...

Answer (score 0):

The field objInfo is a char pointer (char*), so you must assign a pointer to it, gotten by & on an "object". So `objAttr.objInfo = &digestO;` is the closest attempt, but &digest0 is a pointer to digestInfo, so you probably want to change

```
typedef struct
{
   dsUint16_t   stVersion;                       
... (omitted for clarity)
   dsUint16_t   objInfoLength;                  
   char         *objInfo;                       
... (omitted for clarity)
}ObjAttr;
```

to

```
typedef struct
{
   dsUint16_t   stVersion;                       
... (omitted for clarity)
   dsUint16_t   objInfoLength;                  
   digestInfo    *objInfo;                       
... (omitted for clarity)
}ObjAttr;
```

Comment: Ben, thanks for your answer. My problem, is I am linking to a 3rd party library, so I cannot change the ObjAttr struct. Is there another way, that I can copy my object into that objInfo, that is valid C?

Comment: But you seem to have access to the source (you're posting a subset, after all). Otherwise you'll just have to maintain it elsewhere.

Comment: I have the header files of the 3rd party library that I am compiling with (which is their ObjAttr struct).  I'm assuming that I can't just modify the header, since when I link to the library that would fail - or some other expected thing might happen? My digestInfo struct I can change anyway,I need, but I want that "data" to be stored in ObjAttr.objInfo, so that when I call it back out of the application (that is storing it), it is in a format that I understand and can use.

Comment: then I guess you can turn digestInfo into one formatted string array, since that's what objInfo is. As is, you can't do anything